# Printing hex characters

Tags: c++

I would like to understand the results of printing out a char and an unsigned char.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int8_t a = 0xA1;
    uint8_t b = 0xA1;
    printf("0x%x,", a);
    printf("0x%x,", b);
    std::cout << std::hex << a << ",";
    std::cout << std::hex << b << std::endl;
}
```

Result

```
0xffffffa1,0xa1,�,�
```

I don't understand why the signed char turns into an uint or int, and why std::hex fails miserably.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int8_t a = 0xA1;` causes signed overflow, thus the behavior is undefined. If you turned on correct compiler flags, you'd [get](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4Lw_Uh) something like:

```
error: overflow in conversion from 'int' to 'int8_t' {aka 'signed char'} changes value from '161' to '-95' [-Werror=overflow]

    8 |     int8_t a = 0xA1;

      |                ^~~~
```

Besides, `%x` expects an `unsigned int`. This also causes undefined behavior. You meant to do something like:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int8_t a = 42; // Doesnt overflow
    uint8_t b = 42;
    std::printf("%#x,", static_cast<unsigned int>(a));
    std::printf("%#x,", static_cast<unsigned int>(b));
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned int>(a) << ",";
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned int>(b) << std::endl;
}
```

Output: `0x2a,0x2a,2a,2a`

Comment: Yikes. I really need to start memorizing hex values, as I thought A1 was a lot smaller. Thanks.